# Transfer a string from MainWindow to a RichTextBox in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, serial-port, richtextbox

I'm new in WPF, I have a UserControl that called **Communication** which responsible to connect \ disconnect to a SerialPort class.

Also, there is a LOG which is a RichTextBox and my purpose is to read and write strings which running on the SerialPort buffer, and display them on that log.

The Application looks like that:

[image]

Communication XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="0,0,0,10">
        <TextBlock Text="Choose COM:"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   />
        <ComboBox Name="ComboBoxPorts"
                  Height="25"
                  Width="75"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                  SelectionChanged="ComboBoxPorts_SelectionChanged" />
        <Button Name="Button_open_port"
                Content="Connect"
                Height="25"
                Click="open_port_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Row="1">
        <ScrollViewer Name="ScrollViewer_LogView"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      Height="220">
            <RichTextBox Name="RichTextBox_logView"
                         Height="220"
                         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Also in Code of that UserControl I have function which called "Print to log" that works and print on the LOG the strings that I'm giving her.

Communication CS Code:

```
public partial class Communication : UserControl
{
    public SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort();
    public delegate void DataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e);
    public event DataReceivedEventHandler DataReceivedEvent;

    public Communication()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
    }

    private void open_port_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            // If Close
            if (mySerialPort.IsOpen == false)
            {
                mySerialPort.PortName = ComboBoxPorts.SelectedItem.ToString();
                mySerialPort.Open();
                Button_open_port.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Tomato);
                Button_open_port.Content = "Disconnect";
            }
            // If Open
            else
            {
                mySerialPort.Close();
                Button_open_port.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);
                Button_open_port.Content = "Connect";
            }
    }

    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    { 
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        // Print it on the Log
        Print_To_Log(indata, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red, 0);
    }

    /// <param name="data">string of the data</param>
    /// <param name="color">object "Brushes.xxxxx"  -> (xxxxx=name of the color)</param>
    /// <param name="direction">1 for TX (sending data), 0 or anything else for RX(receiveing data)</param>
    public void Print_To_Log(string data, SolidColorBrush color, int direction = 0)
    {
        // Print it on the Log
        RichTextBox_logView.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
        {
            TextRange rangeOfTextInput = new TextRange(RichTextBox_logView.Document.ContentEnd, RichTextBox_logView.Document.ContentEnd);
            if (direction == 1)
                rangeOfTextInput.Text = ">>  ";
            else
                rangeOfTextInput.Text = "<<  ";
            rangeOfTextInput.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, color);
            RichTextBox_logView.AppendText(data + "\r");
            RichTextBox_logView.ScrollToEnd();
        });
    }
```

I have a **MainWindow** that contains TextBox and Button. Also that MainWindow contains in the XAML the UserControl **Communication**.

I want be able to write a string on that TextBox, and after clicking the button "Send", transfer the string to the SerialPort (which appears in the UserControl) and it will appears on the LOG.

Also, when I receive something on the SerialPort, it should also appears on that LOG.

How I'm doing that? Please Help.

MainWindow XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <MyProject:Communication Grid.Row="0"
                             Margin="0,10"
                             Width="450"
                             Height="250"/>
    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBox Name="TextBox_input"
                 Width="200"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Margin="50,0,20,0"/>
        <Button Name="Button_send"
                Width="80"
                Content="_Send"
                Click="Button_send_Click"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow code:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void Button_send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Constructor of what? and when exactly?

Comment: I misread your issue, but you still can pass the parameters through your UserControl's constructor

Comment: After I clicking the "Send" Button, how I can transfer the string which in my TextBox to the UserControl's constructor, if I don't have any instance of it?
Can you write me code example please?

Comment: You can retrieve its text by doing string myVar = this.TextBox_input.Text and then pass myVar through the constructor from your UserControl

Comment: Since the UserControl are defined in XAML and are initialized by the code InitializeComponent() of my MainWindow I am not able to use a constructor to pass a reference of my TextBox.text string to the UserControls.

Comment: public Communication(string myString) 
{
MyStringInTheUC = myString;
        InitializeComponent();
        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can is you can give Name property to that particular usercontrol which u had added in your mainwindow.xaml and then can get the think

--> Assign  Name Property to  userControl

By adding   x:Name="ucCommunication"   to your MyProject:Communication object.

--> Now Make Necessary changes to the  UserControl

(Make one Helper Function)

```
public void GetStringDataFromControl(string content)
{
  ///write here your required function to execute when u get send button clicked and had textbox text in hand
}
```

--> Now Pass RichTextbox Text to your  UserControl by calling public member function like this

```
private void Button_send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      //here call usecontrol helper function 
     ucCommunication.GetStringDataFromControl("write the string you want to pass.Here in your case get richtextbox text and convert it to string and pass");
}
```

In case of any query or concern please let me.  If it really helps then please mark it as answer.